# Is it possible to have an element "pass through" structural rules?

Tags: html, css

I'll start with an example

```css
.Item {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
  }

#AllStuffs {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  }
```

```html
<div id="AllStuffs">
  <div class="Item">I am static</div>
  <div id="DynamicTexts">
    <div class="Item">Lets pretend</div>
    <div class="Item">that we are dynamic</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, it would be convenient for me to have an element that separates out dynamic elements from static ones (or maybe dynamic elements from multiple sources or whatever), in this case "DynamicTexts".

At the same time, I want that separator element to be completely invisible to the document structure and obey css rules as if all the "item" classed elements were direct children of the "AllStuffs" element, which in this case would result in 3 red boxes in a row.

Is there a way to force this "pass through" mode on an element?

note: not interested in other solutions for the hypothetical problem, only interested whether or not this particular approach is viable.

Comment: You might have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM

Comment: Why can't you just add separate classes to static and dynamic elements?

Comment: @SalmanA I can but that's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

Here, using floats:

```css
.Item {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
  float: left;
  }
#AllStuffs, #DynamicTexts {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
#AllStuffs {
  overflow: auto; // clearfix the floats inside
  }
```

```html
<ul id="AllStuffs">
  <li class="Item">I am static</div>
  <li>
    <ul id="DynamicTexts">
      <li class="Item">Lets pretend</li>
      <li class="Item">that we are dynamic</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Although it isn't required to solve your issue, I converted the containers to lists and items to list items to improve semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i'm understand your description. But according to solution in first answer i make similar in flexbox:

```css
.Item {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
  }

#AllStuffs {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
#DynamicTexts {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div id="AllStuffs">
  <div class="Item">I am static</div>
  <div id="DynamicTexts">
    <div class="Item">Lets pretend</div>
    <div class="Item">that we are dynamic</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the dynamic box not to be in the DOM. For example you want to apply the following css rules to all boxes, right?

```
AllStuffs>Item
{
    color: green;
}
```

There is no option to bypass the DynamicText element in this case. 
To resolve this problem, you have to use JS, because you want to change the DOM of the website.

If you only want to change the floating, see the other answers.

Hope this is, what you're asking for.